# hide an element by click on window object after showing element on Dom with vanilla js?

Tags: javascript

There is a button in my dom after clicking on that element another element will show, I want to hide this element by clicking on the window object with vanilla js
this is my code for show element

```
const button = document.querySelector('.button');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
button.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.target.style.display = "none";
    box.style.display = "block";
})
```

this is my code for hiding the box

```
window.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  e.target.style.display = "block";
  box.style.display = "none";
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need, see the comments

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const myButton = document.querySelector(".button");

myButton.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.stopPropagation(); // You need to stop propagation, if not the event will bubble to the window and fire the click event of window
    e.target.style.display = "none"; // Hise the button 
    box.style.display = "block";  // Show the box
})

window.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
  box.style.display = "none"; // Hide the box
  myButton.style.display = "block"; // Show the button
})
```

```css
.box {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">This is the box</div>
<button class="button">Button</button>
```